# How to create RegularFileProperty from a string or classpath resource?

Tags: gradle

I'm creating a Gradle plugin that configures another Gradle plugin. One piece of configuration is to provide `RegularFileProperty` instance. How can I create instance of such interface if I just have `String` object in hand? Or a resource bundled with my plugin?

With `TextResource` I was doing it by `resources.text.fromString(...)` or

```
        project.with {
            resources.text.fromString(buildscript.classLoader.getResource(resourceName).text)
        }
```

What would be equivalent snippet to create a `RegularFileProperty`? If the only way is by a temporary file, how and where should I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I reference a file that is packaged within the jar of my custom Gradle plugin.  I have a common `test-rules.xml` config for SpotBugs I want to be applied to any project applying my plugin.

```
String spotBugsTestRules = getClass().getResourceAsStream("config/spotbugs/test-rules.xml").text
File spotBugsTestRulesFile = File.createTempFile("test-rules", ".xml")
spotBugsTestRulesFile.write(spotBugsTestRules)

project.tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('spotbugs') && it.name.endsWith('Test')
}.all {
    it.includeFilter = spotBugsTestRulesFile
}
```

This code reads the resource file into a String and then outputs it back as a temp file.  This is because the `includeFilter` property is a `RegularFilePropery` and needs to be pointing to an actual file on the file system.

Answer (score 4):

A `RegularFileProperty` is a type of provider that allows you to lazily provide a value of type `RegularFile`. So I think you might not be asking how to create a provider, but rather how to configure it with a RegularFile.

A `RegularFile` represents a fixed file on the file system. So if all you have is content for the file, you need to save it as a file somewhere - preferably somewhere in the build folder.

You can configure the provider with a new value through the setter method. There are currently not so many ways to get an instance of `RegularFile`, but usually you get it via various methods on a [ProjectLayout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ProjectLayout.html):

```
myRegularFileProvider.set(project.layout.buildDirectory.file("myFile.txt"))
```

Comment: OK, and how can I create such file in a build directory? Is there any convention for doing that?

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up creating a temporary file and it works for me.

```
    def file = File.createTempFile("config", ".xml")
    file.write '<config/>'
    extension.myRegularFileProperty.set(file)
```